# Is second order method worse than first order method?

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-analysis

I was thinking about an elementary question in numerical analysis.

When discretizing an ordinary differential equation, it is well known that a second order method is more accurate than a first order method, since the truncation error for second order method is O(dx^2) and O(dx) for the first order method. This is true when 0 < dx < 1.

what if dx > 1? For example, the domain is 0 to 10000 and the mesh size is 1000, then dx = 10. In this case, is the second order method not accurate as first order method, since dx^2 = 100 and dx = 10? We can encounter this when dealing with large scale problem, such as climate modeling (the cloud size could be several kilometers).

Answer (score 1):

A second order method is not more accurate than a first order method because dx^2 < dx, for some value of dx. It's a statement about the asymptotic *rate* of convergence for small dx.

Additionally, comparing dx^2 to dx directly doesn't make sense, because dx isn't a unitless quantity, it's a length. So you're trying to compare an area to a length, which is meaningless.

In [big-O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), if a quantity converges with O(dx^2), then that typically means that the error is of the form e = a2 dx^2 + a3 dx^3 + ...  The leading coefficient a2 is in the units of X/meters^2, where X is whatever units your error is in, and maybe you use some other length instead of meters. Similarly, for a first order solution, the error is in the form b1 dx + b2 dx^2 + ..., where b1 is in units of X/meters.

So if you decide you can neglect the non-leading terms (which you probably can't for large values of dx), the comparison isn't between dx^2 and dx, it's between a2 dx^2 and b1 dx. There is obviously a cross over between these two error terms, but it's not at dx=1, it's at dx = b1/a2. If your discretization is that coarse, you're probably not in the asymptotic regime in which you can ignore higher-order terms, and your solution is probably very inaccurate anyway.